# Using ng-content to select base class

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I have a component `Parent` that content projects `Child` components as follows. In this case, `Child` is an abstract base class that is extended by components `ChildA` and `ChildB`. Here's an example use cased in a user's template:

```
<parent>
  <child-a></child-a> // or child-b
</parent>
```

In the `Parent`'s template I want to use `<ng-content>` to content project the `Child` component.  However, I want to be able to use `<ng-content>` and somehow select either the `<child-a>` or `<child-b>`, something like:

```
<ng-content select="child-a | child-b"></ng-content>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a comma separated list like this:

```
<ng-content select="child-a,child-b"></ng-content>
```

Comment: Okay.  Is there a way I can select via the *base class* somehow?  I'm guessing no because it's just a class and not a "component". I'll probably end up doing as you suggested, but I'm not a *huge* fan of it because then the parent class has to "know" about the different types of child components it needs to support.

Comment: No unfortunately, you can only select based on what is visible in the template using selectors, which are CSS classes, attributes or element names

Comment: Although they could add a HostBinding to the abstract class so that the component always has a specific class on it that they would then use for the selector.

```@HostBinding('class.some-class') someField: boolean = true;```
```<ng-content select=".some-class"></ng-content>```